# Hosting MVC Asp.net Application in IIS in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7.5

When I Add new web site in IIS and open in browser it shows me the list of directory instead of web page in windows server 2008 R2. I am unable to run application (MVC Asp.net Application). Please help me where I am wrong Or guide me with the steps that I need to perform.

Comment: Have you tried setting a default route for website in IIS?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: all the basic rules i followed to host in windows server 2008 R2 and when i host this application on windows 8 then it is working fine but when i host this in windows server 2008 R2 it show the directory not web page...